# Echarts4r : Format labels in heatmap

Tags: heatmap, echarts

Is there any possibility to format labels in heatmap? I don't [see](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-heatmap.label) that `label` has some `formatter`option. I would like to separate thousands and round decimals in labels.

```
v <- LETTERS[1:10]
matrix <- data.frame(
  x = sample(v, 300, replace = TRUE), 
  y = sample(v, 300, replace = TRUE), 
  z = rnorm(300, 5000, 1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) 

matrix %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_heatmap(y, z, label = list(show = TRUE)) %>% 
  e_visual_map(z)
```

Comment: I'm afraid the original JavaScript library does not allow that :(

Answer (score 0):

In `series[i]-heatmap.tooltip.formatter` we can write a function which returns the rounded of values.

[It's clearly explained here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-heatmap)